# class='col-md-12' is not working correctly in firefox but working in chrome?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I have desgin login form, If username and password is mismatched then then I am giving error above to login form. For error, I am using following code.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class='col-md-12' style="color:orange;" >
         <p> {{error statement}} </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note: class='col-md-12' is bootstrap class**

The above is code is working correctly in chrome but in firefox browser, username text area is shifted in right direction, but in chrome it is aligned with password text area. If I remove `class='col-md-12'` then I is also working correctly in firefox, why this is happening?

Comment: Perhaps add some screenshots of what is expect/unexpected, and the relevant CSS! :)

Comment: @Luke, class='col-md-12' id bootstrap class

Comment: `.col-*` classes need to be nested directly inside a `.row`. It serves no purpose here anyway. Just remove it and move the `style` to the `.form-group`

Answer (score 0):

Try shifting `style="color:orange;"` to `<p>` tag.

It works well for me, hope this will resolve your issue.

Col-md-* may have inherited css from framework that is conflicting with the style you applied.